# How to find the last valid information possibly spread over several log files

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, find, grep

I have a fleet of buses that send me a monitoring log file every morning regarding the status of the vehicle the previous day. The log updates various information every 5 minutes. Among the data collected are the GPS coordinates.

Longitude and latitude are represented on separate lines.
The logs for each vehicle are stored in a separate folder. In this folder is a sub-folder containing all the log files. Each logfile starts with "monitoring" and then followed by the creation date and time. So I have a log file for every day in this folder.

File example:

```
07-15 15:48:28.064 [INFO ] dataset.up.throughput : 0
07-15 15:53:16.425 [INFO ] system.disk.used.total : 731 MB
07-15 15:53:16.426 [INFO ] system.mem.used.total : 458 MB
07-15 15:53:16.427 [INFO ] system.cpu.usage : 9,99
07-15 15:53:16.520 [INFO ] msg.nbr.expired : 0
07-15 15:53:16.521 [INFO ] msg.nbr.received : 0
07-15 15:53:16.522 [INFO ] msg.send.throughput : 0
07-15 15:53:16.523 [INFO ] msg.received.throughput : 0
07-15 15:53:16.590 [INFO ] dataset.nbr.jobs.queue : 6
07-15 15:53:16.590 [INFO ] dataset.nbr.jobs.inprogress : 6
07-15 15:53:16.590 [INFO ] dataset.nbr.jobs.expired : 0
07-15 15:53:16.590 [INFO ] dataset.down.throughput : 0
07-15 15:53:16.590 [INFO ] dataset.up.throughput : 0
07-15 15:53:16.591 [INFO ] posn.altitude : 80.0 m
07-15 15:53:16.591 [INFO ] posn.longitude : 4° 18' 34"
07-15 15:53:16.591 [INFO ] posn.latitude : 50° 53' 35"
07-15 15:53:16.591 [INFO ] posn.speed : 23.55 m/s
07-15 15:53:16.591 [INFO ] posn.track : 235° 1' 30"
07-15 15:53:16.591 [INFO ] posn.source : GPS_DR
07-15 15:53:16.591 [INFO ] posn.timestamp : Wed Jul 15 13:53:15 CEST 2015
07-15 15:53:16.592 [INFO ] mpm.online : false
07-15 15:53:16.592 [INFO ] mpm.online.ts : 0
07-15 15:58:16.383 [INFO ] system.disk.used.total : 732 MB
```

---

Normally I use a shell command like this:

```
find /path/to /vehicle/folder/vehicleID/ -type d -name 'FolerContainingLogFiles' -exec sh -c "ls {}/monitoring* -t | head -1 | grep "posn.l" {}/monitoring* | tail -2" >> /path/results.log ";" ;
```

This works just fine in normal situations but sometimes a bus is moved only for a very short time on the parking lot. In that case the GPS cannot synchronise with the satellites and therefore the logging gives me a `value = "0"` for the longitude and latitude.

And it is here that the problem starts:

1. if the last coordinates are = "0" then I need to go up the file and try to find the last non-zero value.
2. sometimes, the file has nothing but zero values. In this case I need to go to the previous file and start looking for a non-zero value and so on.

I tried to write a bash script but can't get the correct output for some reason.

```
find $zoekPad -type d -name 'mobiguider-logs-archive' | while read line; do

cmdOutputLon=$(ls $line/monitoring* -t | head -1 | grep "posn.lo" $line/monitoring* | tail -1 )
lonDD=$(echo $cmdOutputLon | awk -F':' '{print $5}' | awk '{printf ("%.8f\n",$1+$2/60+$3/3600)}')
cmdOutputLon=$cmdOutputLon";"$lonDD
cmdOutputLat=$(ls $line/monitoring* -t | grep "posn.la" $line/monitoring* | tail -1)
latDD=$(echo $cmdOutputLat | awk -F':' '{print $5}' | awk '{printf ("%.8f\n",$1+$2/60+$3/3600)}')
cmdOutputLat=$cmdOutputLat";"$latDD
huidigeIndexStart=1
while [[ true ]]
do
    loopCount=1000
    cmdOutputLon=$(ls $line/monitoring* -t | grep "posn.lo" $line/monitoring* | sed -n $huidigeIndexStart,$huidigeIndexStart"p")
    echo $huidigeIndexStart
    lonDD=$(echo $cmdOutputLon | awk -F':' '{print $5}' | awk '{printf ("%.8f\n",$1+$2/60+$3/3600)}')
    cmdOutputLon=$cmdOutputLon";"$lonDD
    cmdOutputLat=$(ls $line/monitoring* -t | grep "posn.la" $line/monitoring* | sed -n $huidigeIndexStart,$huidigeIndexStart"p")
    latDD=$(echo $cmdOutputLat | awk -F':' '{print $5}' | awk '{printf ("%.8f\n",$1+$2/60+$3/3600)}')
    cmdOutputLat=$cmdOutputLat";"$latDD

    if ! [[ $cmdOutputLon =~ '0° 0'\'' 0"' ]]
    then
        echo $cmdOutputLon >> $schrijfPad
        echo $cmdOutputLat >> $schrijfPad
        continue 2
    fi

    if [ $huidigeIndexStart -gt $loopCount ] && [ $loopCount -gt 0 ]
    then
        echo $cmdOutputLon >> $schrijfPad
        echo $cmdOutputLat >> $schrijfPad
        continue 2
    fi

    huidigeIndexStart=$(($huidigeIndexStart + 1))
done

echo $cmdOutputLon >> $schrijfPad
echo $cmdOutputLat >> $schrijfPad
done


now=$(date +"%m_%d_%Y_%H:%M:%S");
echo $now
echo "Einde LastGPS_allvehicules.sh "$now >> /home/mxtbp/raid5/logs/rsync/Rsync_log.txt ;
```

Can anyone help?